# Working with Limit on a Root expression

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, series-expansion

I am trying to diagonalize a somewhat larger matrix that is dependent on several parameters. Applying, say, `Eigenvalues` to that matrix is quite straightforward, but Mathematica apparently hits some polynomial equations that it cannot solve and returns some expressions containing `Root`, which are again dependent on said parameters. The expressions can be quite convolved, but for the sake of this qustion, let's assume that Mathematica returns $k - kx + x^5=0$, where $x$ is the free variable and $k$ is one of the parameters.

To proceed, I would like to make use of the knowledge that $k$ is very large, indeed much larger than all other involved parameters. Mathematically, I would like to look at the limit $k\rightarrow\infty$. Looking at the equation $k - kx + x^5=0$, it is apparent that $x_0\rightarrow1$ will hold for any solution as $k\rightarrow\infty$. However, Mathematica does not seem to share that insight:

```
In= Limit[Root[k - k #1 + #1^5 &, 1], k -> Infinity]
```

> `Out= Limit[Root[k - k #1 + #1^5 &, 1], k -> ∞]`

Is there any way to make Mathematica realize that it can further simplify this kind of expression? Since everything involved here is polynomial, it should in principle be possible to solve that task by suitable expression replacements, but that sounds very cumbersome and error-prone. So it would be great to find a way other than that approach.

---

Edit: As Carl hinted in his comment, my question might actually be an instance of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). So here are some more details. A sample matrix could be the one given below. Most entries are close to the diagonal, but there are also some off-diagonal entries. The determinant is always zero.

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 -k  & \gamma  & 0 & 0 & \delta  & 0 & \epsilon  & 0 \\
 0 & -\gamma -k  & 0 & 0 & 0 & \delta  & 0 & \epsilon  \\
 k  & 0 & -\xi  & \gamma  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & k  & 0 & -\gamma -\xi  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \xi  & 0 & -\delta -\theta  & \gamma  & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \xi  & 0 & -\gamma -\delta -\theta  & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \theta  & 0 & -\epsilon  & \gamma  \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \theta  & 0 & -\gamma -\epsilon  \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The matrix itself describes a system of ODEs and I'm interested in long-term behaviour $t\rightarrow\infty$ as well as in solutions for special starting conditions. Diagonalization is the easiest approach to that, but without doubt not the only one, nor the smartest.

Comment: An example matrix would be helpful, as there are probably better approaches than taking the limit of symbolic eigenvalues.

Comment: How does one generate your Root object with the parameter k from your matrix?

Comment: Which version of Mathematica are you using? With either v11.2.0 or v11.1.1


`Limit[Root[k - k #1 + #1^5 &, 1], k -> Infinity]` evaluates to

`1`

Comment: @CarlWoll I changed the matrix and now the `Root` object should be produced by just calling `Eigenvalues`.

Comment: @BobHanlon I'm currently using v10.0.2.0. Interesting observation, anyway. I might actually be able to access a newer version.

Comment: treating `x` as a function of `k`, as `k` gets large you know `x[k]` stabilizes, so its derivative goes to zero. So maybe a series expansion here is useful? I have in mind e.g. `Series[D[k - k*x[k] + x[k]^5, k], {x'[k], 0, 2}]`.

Comment: Can't you divide your matrix by $k$, send $k\to \infty$, get the eigenvalues, and then multipy back by $k$? Did you want more than just the leading term?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Series`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series) instead of [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root):

```
Series[Root[k - k #1 + #1^5&, 1], {k, Infinity, 2}] //TeXForm
```

> $1+\frac{1}{k}+\frac{5}{k^2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^3\right)$

Comment: Interesting approach. Would there be an easy way to apply this method via replacements? It would be handy if I could replace any `Root` in the output by `Series[Root[#]]&`.

Comment: @ranguwud Can't you just use `Series` on the whole thing?

Comment: Unfortunately it appears that one cannot just throw `Series` on the whole expression. Even for the simple example, there are problems. If I look at the 5th root instead of the first with `Series[Root[k - k #1 + #1^5 &, 5], {k, Infinity, 2}]`, then the leading term is $k^{1/4}$, which seems to be a wrong result to me.

Comment: @ranguwud I actually think the Series for the 5th root is correct. The problem is that Series produces the exact same result for roots 2, 3, and 4.

Comment: @ranguwud Consider `NSolve[10^8 - 10^8 x + x^5 == 0, x]`. One of the roots is just 1. The other roots, though, have a magnitude on the order of $(10^8)^{1/4} = 100$: